# Mysql - best setup for 4 replication databases and another standalone

Tags: mysql, replication, architecture

we would like to merge on one server 2 mysql instances coming from 2 different server :

- 4 databases on the first instance, which is a replication slave, which are replicated from a master
- 1 database on the second instane, which is standalone (a datawarehouse)

What do you think is a better setup, i think specially to the exploitation/maintenance :

- having 2 mysql instances to run : for the first, the 4 replicated databases, on the second, the standalone one
- one instance to manage both types

Thanks very much.

Comment: do you need more information ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 4 slaves from one master? If so, that's a pretty common configuration for read scaling. INSERT, UPDATE, MERGEm, and DELETE on the master. Then SELECT from any of the saves to spread out the read load. Most versions of MySQL will support this.

I'm not sure where the stand-alone server gets its data. Is it the master? Is it another slave.

If the stand-along server is mean to store all of the data from multiple databases on other servers, you may want a multi-source replication slave. Multi-source replication means that one server has many masters from which it replicates.

Look for a version of MySQL that supports multi-source replication. I'm not sure the Oracle release does this yet. At any rate, I prefer MariaDB; which supports multi-source replication in version 10 (and maybe earlier, but use the newest).

By the way, if you want multiple master databases acting in a cluster, the Galera cluster addition to MariaDB is really useful.

Comment: i just edited my description, thanks for your interest.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm still unclear what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: can you please tell me what do you want me to develop ? Thanks

Comment: **Well:** "we would like to merge on one server 2 mysql instances coming from 2 different server[s]" leads me to recommend a version of MySQL that supports multi-source replication. One server acting as a slave for many others. 
**But:** "4 databases on the first instance, which is a replication slave, which are replicated from a master" tells me that there is only one server from which you are replicating 4 databases. This is a single source that happens to have 4 databases in it. Normal MySQL replication can do that.